# WPF How correct modify view from ICommand with MVVM

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, mvvm

I need to load ComboBox `ItemsSource` before the control is expanded. And if loading failed I want set border brush color to red and show tooltip with error. Can I do this in `ICommand.Execute` method or should use something like `ValidationRule`?

**Code:**

```
class ViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public string Server { get {...} set {...} }
    public ObservableCollection<string> ServerCollection { get; }

    public ICommand LoadServerListCommand { get; }

    protected ConnectionViewModel()
    {
        ServerCollection = new ObservableCollection<string>();
        LoadServerListCommand = new DelegateCommand( LoadServerList );
    }

    private void LoadServerList( object param )
    {
        var comboBox = param as ComboBox;
        if ( comboBox != null && !comboBox.IsDropDownOpen )
        {
            try
            {
                ServerCollection.Clear();
                ///... Load();

                comboBox.BorderBrush = //default;
                comboBox.ToolTip = null;
            }
            catch( InvalidOperationException ex )
            {
                comboBox.BorderBrush = //red;
                comboBox.ToolTip = new ToolTip()
                {
                    Content = ex.Message
                };
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**XAML:**

```
<ComboBox x:Name="cbServer" ItemsSource="{Binding ServerCollection}" 
          SelectedItem="{Binding Server, Mode=TwoWay}">
    <i:Interaction.Triggers>
        <i:EventTrigger EventName="PreviewMouseDown">
            <i:InvokeCommandAction Command="{Binding Path=LoadServerListCommand}" 
                                   CommandParameter="{Binding ElementName=cbServer}"/>
        </i:EventTrigger>
    </i:Interaction.Triggers>
</ComboBox>
```

Comment: You should never modify your View from your ViewModel the view should change itself! Take a dive into DataBinding i think that could help you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could add a property to the view model that indicates whether the loading was successful and bind to this property and change the appropriate properties of the `ComboBox` using a `Style` and a DataTrigger in the view.

Setting the `BorderBrush` of a `ComboBox` requires you to define a custom template for its `ToggleButton` though: https://blog.magnusmontin.net/2014/04/30/changing-the-background-colour-of-a-combobox-in-wpf-on-windows-8/

It will be easier to wrap the `ComboBox` in a `Border` element:

```
<Border BorderThickness="1">
    <ComboBox x:Name="cbServer" ItemsSource="{Binding ServerCollection}"
                  SelectedItem="{Binding Server, Mode=TwoWay}">
        <ComboBox.Resources>
            <SolidColorBrush x:Key="{x:Static SystemColors.WindowFrameBrushKey}" Color="Red"/>
        </ComboBox.Resources>
        <i:Interaction.Triggers>
            <i:EventTrigger EventName="Loaded">
                <i:InvokeCommandAction Command="{Binding Path=LoadServerListCommand}" />
            </i:EventTrigger>
        </i:Interaction.Triggers>
        <ComboBox.Style>
            <Style TargetType="ComboBox">
                <Setter Property="ToolTip" Value="{Binding Error}" />
                <Style.Triggers>
                    <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Error.Length, FallbackValue=0}" Value="0">
                        <Setter Property="ToolTip" Value="{x:Null}" />
                    </DataTrigger>
                </Style.Triggers>
            </Style>
        </ComboBox.Style>
    </ComboBox>
    <Border.Style>
        <Style TargetType="Border">
            <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="Red" />
            <Style.Triggers>
                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Error.Length, FallbackValue=0}" Value="0">
                    <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="{x:Null}" />
                </DataTrigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
    </Border.Style>
</Border>
```

**View Model:**

```
private void LoadServerList(object parameter)
{
    try
    {
        //throw new InvalidOperationException("test");
        ServerCollection.Clear();
        ///... Load();
        Error = string.Empty;
    }
    catch (InvalidOperationException ex)
    {
        Error = ex.Message;
    }
}

private string _error;
public string Error
{
    get { return _error; }
    set { _error = value; NotifyPropertyChanged(); }
}


public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
private void NotifyPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] String propertyName = "")
{
    if (PropertyChanged != null)
        PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
}
```